# RxJava: last item is not emitted while using publish(), debounce(), buffer(), skip() together to capture bursts of events

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm playing around with Rx and there's something that doesn't behave as I'd expect. Original code with detailed comments on the goal to be achieved is [here](https://github.com/reark/reark/blob/a4f39c58ada5a58222337df3474801b2d20b9092/reark/src/main/java/io/reark/reark/data/stores/cores/ContentProviderStoreCoreBase.java) (see groupOperations()).

```
public static void lostLastItemVersion1() {
    rangeWhichNeverCompletes(3).publish(stream ->
            stream.buffer(
                    Observable.amb(
                            stream.debounce(100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
                            stream.skip(2))
                            .first()
                            .repeatWhen(observable -> observable)))
            .subscribe(operations ->
                    System.out.println("Buffer size: " + operations.size()));    
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
        System.out.println("FINISH");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}

private static Observable<Integer> rangeWhichNeverCompletes(int limit) {
    return Observable.create(emitter -> {
                for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
                    emitter.onNext(i);
                }
            },
            Emitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER);
}
```

Expected output:

```
Buffer size: 3
FINISH
```

Actual output:

```
Buffer size: 2
FINISH
```

Last item is not buffered...

The same unsatisfactory result with changed code:

```
public static void lostLastItemVersion2() {
    ConnectableObservable<Integer> stream = rangeWhichNeverCompletes(3)
            .publish();

    stream.buffer(
            Observable.amb(
                    stream.debounce(100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
                    stream.skip(2))
                    .first()
                    .repeatWhen(observable -> observable))
            .subscribe(operations ->
                    System.out.println("Buffer size: " + operations.size()));

    stream.connect();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
        System.out.println("FINISH");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

While debugging I discovered that combination of buffer() and skip() produces strange output:

```
public static void case1() {
    Observable.range(1, 15)
            .publish(stream -> stream.buffer(
                    stream.skip(2)
                            .first()
                            .repeatWhen(observable -> observable)))
            .subscribe(operations ->
                    System.out.println("Buffer size: " + operations.size()));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
        System.out.println("FINISH");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Buffer size: 2
Buffer size: 4
Buffer size: 3
Buffer size: 3
Buffer size: 3
Buffer size: 0
FINISH
```

As I understand last emission of 0 is OK as

> Completion of either the source or the boundary Observable causes the returned Observable to emit the latest buffer and complete.

But why are there buffer sizes of 2 and 4 on the first two emissions? Why not 3 always?

Is there anyone who could describe me what is going on? Is it a bug/feature/expected behaviour? Any clean workarounds?

Comment: I *think* I understand what you're trying to achieve, but why don't the various `window()` operators do what you want?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos What are the _benefits_ of using `window()` instead of `buffer()` in this case?